# ¿Cómo se pasan datos de PHP a Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, json

Soy nuevo en PHP y tengo poco conocimiento de Javascript.

Estoy tratando de crear un Cronometro que obtenga el tiempo límite de una base de datos (SQL SERVER), por lo que al momento de obtener el valor en PHP y asignarla a una variable de función Javascript, me aparece un -1.

He leído que no es lo mismo el tipo objeto PHP que en Javascript y esto se puede resolver con `json_encode()`, sin embargo me sigue apareciendo -1, me podrian guiar, ayudar. Anexo código y de verdad gracias.

```
<?php 
require('db.php');

if ($connection)
{
  $TimEva = 60;

  $rs = odbc_exec($connection,"SELECT time FROM DBO.tablaCrono cr WHERE cr.id = '$EncIdx';");   

  while(odbc_fetch_row($rs))
  {
    $TimEva=odbc_result($rs,"TimEva");
  }

  echo "<div align='center'><h1><label id = 'tiempo'>".$TimEva."</label></h1></div>";

  $rs = odbc_close($connection);
}
else
{
  echo "<div align='center'>no se pudo conectar</div><br />";
}
?>
```

Y en la función Javascript tengo lo siguiente

```
var label = document.getElementById("tiempo"),
minutos = <?php  echo json_encode($TimEva,JSON_HEX_TAG);?>,
```

Comment: Gracias por la correccion @Trauma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A continuación muestro un **ejemplo de como pasar datos comunes desde PHP a variables JavaScript**, un string, un array y un objeto. Fíjate el caso del objeto y el uso de [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/es/class.jsonserializable.php), esta función trabaja normalmente con arrays (ver ejemplos), no directamente con objetos.

```
<?php

class Test {
    private $id;
    private $name;

    public function __construct(int $id, string $name)
    {
        $this->id   = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

} // class

$str = 'Hola mundo';
$arr = [
    'id'   => 1,
    'name' => 'Baz'
];
$obj = new Test(2, 'Foo');
$obj2 = [
    $obj->getId(), 
    $obj->getName()
];
?>

<p>This is HTML...</p>
<script>
    var str = <? echo($str); ?>;
    var arr = <? echo(json_encode($arr)); ?>;
    var obj = <? echo(json_encode($obj)); ?>;
    var obj2 = <? echo(json_encode($obj2)); ?>;
    var obj3 = <? echo(json_encode([
        $obj->getId(), 
        $obj->getName()
    ])); ?>;
</script>
```

> Editado

Una forma de pasar directamente objetos de PHP a JavaScript, cuando nosotros implementamos las clases de esos objetos, es usar la interface [JsonSerializable](http://php.net/manual/es/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php). Ejemplo:

```
<?php

class Test2 implements JsonSerializable {
    private $id;
    private $name;

    public function __construct(int $id, string $name)
    {
        $this->id   = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function jsonSerialize(): array
    {
        return [$this->id, $this->name];
    }

} // class

$obj = new Test2(2, 'Foo');

?>

<p>This is HTML...</p>
<script>
    var obj = <? echo(json_encode($obj)); ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: de acuerdo, permiteme probarlo

Comment: Probado y confirmado!. Gracias Orici!